# Appium with Python: App XYZ Won't Launch with Developer Options Enabled - Seeking Workarounds

Tags: android, automated-tests, android-emulator, adb, appium-android

I have been automating an Android mobile app called XYZ using Appium with Python. The app is primarily used for filling forms and uploading photos. Everything was working fine until recently when XYZ received an update. After the update, I encountered an issue: the app refuses to open when Developer Options are enabled on the Android device. Instead, it displays a message asking to turn off Developer Options to use the app.

Is there any way to bypass this restriction and automate the app while Developer Options are enabled? I rely on Developer Options for debugging and various other purposes, so disabling them permanently is not an option.

Here are some details about my setup:

1. Android device connected via ADB.
2. Appium for automation.
3. Python as the scripting language.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue or found a workaround for this problem? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.